# cosine() similarity with sparse matrices in R -- how to speed-up ? (NLP

Tags: r, performance, nlp

I'm using R cosine() function {"lsa" package} to determine the similarity between 2 vectors that are stored in sparse matrices. There are 240,000 lines in each matrix, and 3100 columns.  The calculation time for 1000 lines is about 2 minutes, which translates to 8 hours processing of the full data-set.   I'm looking for ways to expedite this processing time, since I'll have to run it several times.

This is my code:

```
t1 <- Sys.time()
for (i in 1:NROWS) {
  title_cosine_sim[i] <- cosine(dtm_search[i,],dtm_title[i,])
  desc_cosine_sim[i] <- cosine(dtm_search[i,], dtm_desc[i, ])
  if (i%%1000 == 0 ) {
    cat("processed ", i, "rows out of 240,760...", system.time(), "\n")
  }
}
print( difftime( Sys.time(), t1, units = 'sec'))
cat("finish")
```

I tried to use parallel processing but it didn't speed up the process:

```
c1 <- makeCluster(4)
registerDoParallel(c1)

    #calculate title similarity vector
    t1 <- Sys.time()
    title_cosine_sim <- foreach(z = 1:NUMROWS, .combine = 'rbind', .packages =  c('lsa', 'Matrix')) %dopar% {
        cosine( dtm_search[z,],  dtm_title[z,] )
    }

    # calculate description similarity vector
    t1 <- Sys.time() 
    desc_cosine_sim <- foreach(z = 1:NUMROWS, .combine = 'rbind', .packages =  c('lsa', 'Matrix')) %dopar% {
        cosine( dtm_search[z,],dtm_title[z,] )
    }


stopCluster(c1)
print( difftime( Sys.time(), t1, units = 'sec'))
cat("finish PARALLEL processing")
```

Each of the above loops took about 65 seconds for 1000 lines. So there is not much savings in here...

Any idea about improving the code using parallel computing or otherwise are welcome. 
Thank you!

p.s.   Dell 4 cores, 16G RAM, Windows 10.

Comment: This is what I use for a DocumentTermMatrix.  https://github.com/trinker/clustext/blob/master/R/cosine_distance.R

Comment: code is not reproducible - what are title_cosine_sim, dtm_search, dtm_title, dtm_desc?